# Вы не можете отмечать комментарий более одного раза

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, уведомления

А не заменить ли в этой фразе "отмечать" на "голосовать за"?

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Как повторить? D:

Comment: Открываешь страницу в двух вкладках, на одной ставишь комменту плюсик, после этого пытаешься то же самое сделать на второй.

Comment: В оригинале там тоже мутно: "You cannot mark a comment more than once".

Comment: @Suvitruf Как бы то ни было, заменить стоит, — у нас отмечают только тревогами.