# Отсутствие перевода "You are not able to review this item"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

В очереди проверок если вернуться к предыдущей проверке, может появиться следующее сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фразу "You are not able to review this item" могу предложить перевести как "Вы не можете проверить данное сообщение"

Comment: Я бы сказал "проверять", а не "проверить". Хотя, не уверен, какой там контекст - может твой вариант и лучше подойдёт.

Comment: @Qwertiy Почему? На мой взгляд, замена "проверить" на "проверять" будет отображать длительность действия, все же "проверять" несовершенного вида. А в проверке важен результат, а не процесс:)

Comment: Не длительность, а постоянность. И сейчас не можете проверить, и в дальнейшем не сможете. Как ["Вы не можете отмечать комментарий более одного раза"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8842/178988) - "отмечать", а не "отметить". Совершенный вид неявно означает "сейчас", а потом может что-то поменяется. Вы не можете перейти дорогу [пока горит красный - сейчас]. Вы не можете переходить дорогу [в 12 полос где попало - никогда].

Comment: Можете подтвердить, что перевод появился на сайте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Утвердил предложенный перевод

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16279

Добавил точку в конце, как это было в оригинале.

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.3.25.38898

Comment: Перевод появился. Отображается нормально. А что-то случилось? Пишу в комментах к ответу, ибо телефон не предлагает этих греческих букв для обращения через @ 

Comment: @МаксимФисман если появился, значит можно метку красную добавлять.